# Flutter Rive code How can I add text under submenu icons?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

Flutter Rive code How can I add text under submenu icons?

How can I add text under the menu icon as in the picture example?

I don't know since I haven't tried flutter rive before, please help.

I added text under the submenu icons and I solved it.
How can I switch between pages? How can I create a new page and switch to that page when I click on it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWUof.jpg)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rive/rive.dart';

class TabItem {
  TabItem({
    this.stateMachine = "",
    this.artboard = "",
    this.status,
  });

  UniqueKey? id = UniqueKey();
  String stateMachine;
  String artboard;
  late SMIBool? status;

  static List<TabItem> tabItemsList = [
    TabItem(
      stateMachine: "CHAT_Interactivity",
      artboard: "CHAT",
    ),
    TabItem(
      stateMachine: "SEARCH_Interactivity",
      artboard: "SEARCH",
    ),
    TabItem(stateMachine: "TIMER_Interactivity", artboard: "TIMER"),
    TabItem(stateMachine: "BELL_Interactivity", artboard: "BELL"),
    TabItem(stateMachine: "USER_Interactivity", artboard: "USER"),
  ];
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rive/rive.dart' hide LinearGradient;
import 'package:flutter_samples/samples/ui/rive_app/models/tab_item.dart';
import 'package:flutter_samples/samples/ui/rive_app/theme.dart';
import 'package:flutter_samples/samples/ui/rive_app/assets.dart' as app_assets;

class CustomTabBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomTabBar({Key? key, required this.onTabChange}) : super(key: key);

  final Function(int tabIndex) onTabChange;

  @override
  State<CustomTabBar> createState() => _CustomTabBarState();
}

class _CustomTabBarState extends State<CustomTabBar> {
  final List<TabItem> _icons = TabItem.tabItemsList;

  int _selectedTab = 0;

  void _onRiveIconInit(Artboard artboard, index) {
    final controller = StateMachineController.fromArtboard(
        artboard, _icons[index].stateMachine);
    artboard.addController(controller!);

    _icons[index].status = controller.findInput<bool>("active") as SMIBool;
  }

  void onTabPress(int index) {
    if (_selectedTab != index) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedTab = index;
      });
      widget.onTabChange(index);

      _icons[index].status!.change(true);
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
        _icons[index].status!.change(false);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 0, 24, 8),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 768),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
            Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
            Colors.white.withOpacity(0)
          ]),
        ),
        child: Container(
          // Clip to avoid the tab touch outside the border radius area
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: RiveAppTheme.background2.withOpacity(0.8),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: RiveAppTheme.background2.withOpacity(0.3),
                blurRadius: 20,
                offset: const Offset(0, 20),
              )
            ],
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: List.generate(_icons.length, (index) {
              TabItem icon = _icons[index];

              return Expanded(
                key: icon.id,
                child: CupertinoButton(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                  child: AnimatedOpacity(
                    opacity: _selectedTab == index ? 1 : 0.5,
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                    child: Stack(
                        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Positioned(
                            top: -4,
                            child: AnimatedContainer(
                              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                              height: 4,
                              width: _selectedTab == index ? 20 : 0,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: RiveAppTheme.accentColor,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 36,
                            width: 36,
                            child: RiveAnimation.asset(
                              app_assets.iconsRiv,
                              stateMachines: [icon.stateMachine],
                              artboard: icon.artboard,
                              onInit: (artboard) {
                                _onRiveIconInit(artboard, index);
                              },
                            ),
                          )
                        ]),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    onTabPress(index);
                  },
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Flutter Rive code How can I add text under submenu icons?

How can I add text under the menu icon as in the picture example?

I don't know since I haven't tried flutter rive before, please help.

I added text under the submenu icons and I solved it.
How can I switch between pages? How can I create a new page and switch to that page when I click on it?